# Android, array to for loop

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop

i have an array as below which i manually write down the photo link, i have a problem how to convert the array to for loop so that the images will auto updated once i changed the link in my SQL.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);                             

            return i;
        }        

        private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                R.drawable.ctr,
                R.drawable.fb,
                R.drawable.games,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ctr,
                R.drawable.ctr,
                R.drawable.ctr,
                R.drawable.ctr,
                R.drawable.ea,
                R.drawable.fb,
                R.drawable.ctr
        };
```

---

UPDATE
I think i almost solve it:
i put these under the getView()

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/findAppsByID";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "findAppsByID";
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        final String URL = "http://domainURL.com/appsFeaturedWS.asmx";

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject (NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("ID", position+1);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

        try
        {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            final String[] strLogo = new String[resultString.getPropertyCount()];

            for(int j =0; j<resultString.getPropertyCount(); j++)
            {
                SoapObject array = (SoapObject) resultString .getProperty(j);
                strLogo[j] = array.getProperty(5).toString();   //get logo

                i.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(strLogo[j]));
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e){
        }                    

        return i;
    }
```

but my screen just display blank... anything goes wrong?

Comment: have u store value of integer i where int i=R.drawable.image1 or if u try to show image from net than this is not be available bcz apk is read only to display image from net than u have to use lazy adapter for that

Comment: there is not apk, there are images. i store my images url at my server. i want to know is it my code is correct to display the images? especially line i.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(strLogo[j])); anyway, i cant find any example come with array + image url, they all using R.drawable.

Comment: forget all those complexity, i simply try to get the url from net also cannot. this is what i used, please advice me. the apps not even show the image, i changed  i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]); to  i.setImageURI(Uri.parse("http://www.vaultads.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/google-adsense.jpg")); return i;

Comment: if u not get any idea than come at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11936/android-lite for discussion

Answer (score 0):

check the links for   LazyAdapter example [LazyAdapter](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) which is good for getting images from net to show in either gridview,listview or gallary view check it

Answer (score -1):

mImageIds define global

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
            for(int i=0;i<mImageIds.length;i++{
            if(i==position){ 
             i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);                             
             }
            }
            return i;
        }        

        private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                R.drawable.ctr,
                R.drawable.fb,
                R.drawable.games,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ctr,
                R.drawable.ctr,
                R.drawable.ctr,
                R.drawable.ctr,
                R.drawable.ea,
                R.drawable.fb,
                R.drawable.ctr
        };
```

Comment: i dun think u understand my question :)